# Creating a hamburger menu. I used onclick to hide and show the nav items but after changing screen size the nav items do not show or are not flexed

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, responsive

I am trying to create a hamburger menu in mobile view.
When in mobile view the nav-item gets hidden and when i click the menu icon the nav-items will be displayed. But after clicking on the icon and changing the screen size the nav-item dissapper or their display:flex will be disabled.

I am new to Front End so I am getting stuck at this part.

```js
const nameOfElement = document.querySelector(".nav-items")
var dd = "closed"

function dropdown() {
  nameOfElement.style.display = "flex";
  if (dd == "closed") {
    nameOfElement.style.display = "block";
    dd = "opened";
  } else {
    nameOfElement.style.display = "none";
    dd = "closed";
  }
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  background: white;
  margin: 0 0;
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 11.3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02);
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding-left: 64px;
  padding-right: 64px;
}

.logo {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav-items {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  gap: 32px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  gap: 32px;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  padding-left: 8px;
  padding-right: 8px;
}

li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: gray;
}

li a:hover {
  color: black;
}

.button {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

button {
  width: 150px;
  height: 42px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background: #A900E4;
  color: white;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.hamburger {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  nav {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-content: center;
  }
  .nav-items {
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 8px;
    display: none;
  }
  .logo {
    margin-top: 16px;
  }
  ul {
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 32px;
    margin-bottom: 32px;
  }
  .logo {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  li {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .links {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  .button {
    margin-bottom: 32px;
  }
  .hamburger {
    display: block;
  }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <nav>
    <div class="logo">
      <h3>Hello</h3>
      <div class="hamburger">
        <i onclick="dropdown()" class="fa-solid fa-bars"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-items">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">My Works</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="button">
        <button>Get in touch</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/dd8784c5d5.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: The supplied CSS is malformed, perhaps that is a copy/paste error? We cannot make that assumption here...

Answer (score 1):

I just checked your code and it says that show hamburger menu only when screen size is `<=768px` and `>768px` `display:none`

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
.hamburger {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

**That is the reason for it disappearing**

Comment: There appears to more to this than just that small fix.

Answer (score 1):

I dislike using element names to style so I added classes.

I also set up a `@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {` query so that when it is a large screen the hamburger is hidden and the elements always display.  I converted to `em` based on the `font-size:16px;` = `1em` which is the default for most browsers.

Now the big thing is I then used the data attribute with a value so I can use that in CSS rather than direct style from JavaScript which would have to change as the size change on the screen is made; this this is a bit simpler and only uses the CSS but still keeps the hide/show of the menu based on the hamburger click.

A small fix to put the terminating `}` on the media even though that was probably just a typo.

```js
//const nameOfElement = document.querySelector(".nav-items");
//var dd = "closed";
var hamburgerIcon = document.querySelector(".hamburger").querySelector(".hamburger-icon");

hamburgerIcon.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  const nav = document.querySelector(".nav-items");
  var navStyle = nav.dataset.menustyle;
  nav.dataset.menustyle = navStyle == "closed" ? "opened" : "closed";
});
```

```css
* {
  font-size: 16px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  background: white;
  padding-top: 0.75em;
  padding-bottom: 0.75em;
  box-shadow: 0em 0.125em 0.75em 0em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02);
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding-left: 4em;
  padding-right: 4em;
}

.logo {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav-items {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  gap: 2em;
}

.nav-items[data-menustyle="closed"] {
  display: none;
}

.nav-items[data-menustyle="open"] {}

.nav-block {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  gap: 2em;
}

.nav-item {
  padding-left: 0.5em;
  padding-right: 0.5em;
}

.nav-link {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 0.875em;
  color: gray;
  border: 1px solid #00FF00;
}

.nav-link:hover {
  color: black;
}

.button {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.in-touch {
  width: 9.375em height: 2.625em;
  padding: 0.625em 1.25em;
  background-color: #A900E4;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 0.25em;
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 0.875em;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  nav {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-content: center;
  }
  .nav-items {
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 8px;
  }
  .logo {
    margin-top: 1em;
  }
  .nav-block {
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  .logo {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  .nav-item {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .in-touch-container {
    margin-bottom: 2em;
  }
  .nav-items[data-menustyle="closed"] {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .hamburger {
    display: none;
  }
  .nav-items[data-menustyle="closed"] {
    display: flex;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <nav>
    <div class="logo">
      <h3>Hello</h3>
      <div class="hamburger">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-bars hamburger-icon"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-items" data-menustyle="closed">
      <ul class="nav-block">
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">About Me</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">My Works</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="nav-item in-touch-container">
        <button class="in-touch">Get in touch</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/dd8784c5d5.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: could you let me know why   .nav-items[data-menustyle="open"] {}  is left empty?

Comment: Just had it to illustrate options, it can be removed.  IF for example you wanted multiple states you could use the data attribute to show multiple states like a green-yellow-red of a stoplight, things like that. I will remove it since I decided it was not needed here.